# VBNET MSACCESS show text value not foreign key on Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

[image: tblProduct image]

here is an image of my tblProduct table, on Brand field it shows the text value from tblbrand via lookup and selected text value, but when I fill it on a datagridview, it does not show the text value instead its the foreign key. How do I show text value on my datagridview?

[image: datagridview image]

```
 Public Sub LoadProductList()
    DGVProducts.DataSource = Nothing
    DGVProducts.Refresh()
    DGVProducts.RefreshEdit()
    cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from tblProduct", cn)
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cm)

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "tblProduct")
    DGVProducts.DataSource = ds
    DGVProducts.DataMember = "tblProduct"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "#"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Barcode"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Alias"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Product Name"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Brand"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Category"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Principal"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "UOM"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(8).HeaderCell.Value = "Re-order Qty"
    'DGVProducts.Columns(9).HeaderCell.Value = "Qty"
    cn.Close()

    DGVProducts.ClearSelection()
    DGVProducts.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    'DGVProducts.Columns(7).Visible = False
    'DGVProducts.Columns(8).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to do what Access is doing, i.e. get the related data from the other table and display that in your grid. You have two options for doing that. You can either use one query that joins the two tables or use two queries and use a combo box column in the grid to display the related data. You need to decide which you're going to do first, then do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney pardon my ignorance but this was never the case with vs2010, it only started when i installed vs2018. before i made the relationship from tblbrand to tblproduct, i used lookup wizard and selected value text to show up instead of the foreign key.

Comment: Are you talking about a lookup wizard in VS or in Access? Keep in mind that Access is not the database. It is a management application, like SSMS. It can display data in various ways but that doesn't mean that that is what the underlying tables contain. What I described is exactly what I would have done in every version of VS, be it 2010, 2019 or anything else. If there is/was some wizard that I'm not aware of then it would have been the same thing but hidden it from you. You need to do what I said, whether you like it or not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney its the lookup wizard on MSAccess. but i will do your suggestion, query that joins tables. I might also switch to mySQL in the future. Thank you again for your assistance

Comment: If it's in Access then VS versions are irrelevant. As I said, Access is its own application so it can display the data however it wants, but that doesn't change what's actually stored in the database tables under the hood. If you want your application to display the data the way Access does then you have to do what Access does, which is get data from both tables and merge it somehow. If you want a drop-down in the grid to allow the user to select from then that means two separate queries and a combo box column. If it's for display, you could do it that way or join in your query.